# FTPコマンドでユーザ、パスワードのプロンプトが帰ってこない？

Tags: ftp

こんにちは。

知識の少ないインフラ初心者です。
OS:WindowsServer2008
の環境です。
タイトルの件ですが、FTPコマンド（ftp xx.xx.xx.xxの形式）
を実行すると、
Name (xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx): dftpkops
のようなプロンプトが帰り、ユーザ・パスワードを入力する
流れになるとおもっているのですが、
上記環境にて、
「ftp xx.xx.xx.xx」と入力すると、何も聞かれず
「FTP＞」のプロンプトが帰ってくるだけで、
dirを打とうがなにをしても「接続されていません。」と
表示されてしまい、「open」コマンドで接続してもやはり
「FTP＞」のプロンプトが帰ってくるだけの状態です。
何かしら、実行時の権限が不足しているのでは、と思うのですが、
どこを見たらよいかも分からず、困っています。
何か手掛かりなどお分かりの方、回答をよろしくお願いします。

---

追記:
他のFTPクライアント‌​から接続してみたところ、「Name (xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx): 」のようなプロンプトが帰ってきたため、ＦＴＰサーバサービスは起動しているものと判断しています。
またFTPクライアントとF‌​TPサーバの間にはFirewallはない‌​ことも確認いたしました。
そのため、クライ‌​アントの問題ではないかと推測しているので‌​すが、、、。
なお、FTPサーバのOsはU‌​nixでした。

Comment: サーバーで、FTPサーバのサービスが開始されている事を確認しましたか？　ftpコマンドを入力しているマシンと、FTPサーバが動いているマシンは同じですか、それとも別ですか？　マシンの構成について、もう少し具体的な説明をしてください。

Comment: FTPとクライアントの間にFirewallはありますか？「接続されていません」とあるようにサーバーに接続できてないときに質問に書かれたような振る舞いをすると思います。

Comment: Fumu7さん、take88さん、コメントありがとうございます。まず、ＦＴＰサーバ起動有無ですが、他のFTPクライアントから接続してみたところ、「Name (xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx): 」のようなプロンプトが帰ってきたため、ＦＴＰサーバサービスは起動しているものと判断しています。またFTPクライアントとFTPサーバの間にはFirewallはないことも確認いたしました。そのため、クライアントの問題ではないかと推測しているのですが、、、。なお、FTPサーバのOsはUnixでした。

Comment: Windows Firewallを無効にすると何か変化はありますか？